RxJava3 groupBy emitting individual groups instead of grouping by key
Working on updating my app from RxJava2 to RxJava3. I know there are some updates to how groupBy works from reading the documentation, but I'm having trouble understanding why I'm seeing this behaviour. I have sections of code using groupBy that are now emitting individual GroupedFlowables for each item even when the keys match, instead of grouping the emissions under matched GroupedFlowables for the same key.
I've narrowed it down to a repeatable test:
fun runTest() {
                    val eventDTOFlowable = Flowable.just(
                        "item1",
                        "item2",
                        "item3",
                        "item4",
                        "item5",
                        "item6"
                    )
                    val groupedFlowables = eventDTOFlowable.groupBy { _ -> 1 }.cache().toList().blockingGet()
                    output = groupedFlowables.toString()
                }

You can see in the breakpoint output (image below) that groupedFlowables evaluates to a list of each flowable, each with a key of 1, instead of grouping all the flowables under the a single GroupedFlowable with a key of 1. This was working on RxJava2, and checking the Rx groupBy docs I would expect it to do that, but it's not anymore on RxJava3.
Breakpoint output of groupedFlowables
More likely is that my understanding of the changes to groupBy in rxjava3 is wrong, but any clarification is welcome.

You have to start consuming the groups immediately otherwise the operator will not work properly: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-3.0#group-abandonment-in-groupby

@akarnokd I get the same output if I add a flatMap after to add a processing step; does that not qualify as a consumer for this context? Or does it need to be a Subscribe?

With RxJava 3, you have to start consuming the groups, otherwise they will be considered abandoned and recreated every time. See the wiki.
You can start consuming the groups by flatmapping them onto an operator that exhaustively collects all the group's items:
var eventDTOFlowable = Flowable.just(
    "item1",
    "item2",
    "item3",
    "item4",
    "item5",
    "item6"
);

var groupedFlowables = eventDTOFlowable
        .groupBy(x -> 1)
        .flatMapSingle(g -> g.toList())
        .toList()
        .blockingGet()
;
System.out.println(groupedFlowables);

